# Can I ask for salary at a new job based on how long your previous salary increment was?

Tags: salary

Say you've been in your current role for 1 year and 6 months, and you got a salary increment of $10,000 at the 1 year mark. Is it okay to ask your next employer for current salary + $5,000 since you are half way to your next salary increment?

My concern is that if I took a new job at the same salary, the time to the next salary increment would reset, and I would effectively lose 6 months towards what could have been my next increment.

Comment: You can ask for a salary for any reason you see fit. But think about how you're going to pitch it. Trying to justify math used at a previous employer is of no concern to your new employer. Instead you need to ask for this raise because it's what you feel you are worth.

Comment: If I am currently employed in a good position there is no way that I am taking a new job that is not a significant increase in pay.  any time you take a new job there is risk.  Part of what you are asking for is compensation for accepting that risk.  I personally would look for alot more than just the raise you would get if you stuck around.

Answer (score 5):

Your salary with a current employer matters to a potential employer in one way: it's an indicator of how much the market values the skills needed for that type of job.

If they choose to make you an offer, that offer may be equal to, greater than or less than your current salary. They are under no obligation to try to match it, and certainly not to offer you a raise to match a potential raise that you may get sometime in the future.

Now, that said...it's called salary negotiation for a reason.  You can ask for anything you like, they are free to accept, decline or counteroffer -- as are you.  Both of you need to be aware that a counteroffer is the equivalent to declining, NOT conditional acceptance.  If you are unwilling to take the position at a given salary, it's certainly beneficial to the company to be informed of that fact.

Comment: Not much more that can be said. Ask for whatever you like, but be aware that you'll need to persuade them that you're worth it!